# ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED keeps appearing on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, ethernet

I have dual boot installed in my machine. On windows the network interface works fine, however, in ubuntu, I cannot seem to get it to work. For starters, the wireless interface will only capture very dim signals. Unless my computer is standing directly next to the source, it is unusable. Even using ethernet, although the connection works, several times every minute I get a ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED error. This is not only restricted to chrome, it also happens when I am downloading files via ssh. I am thinking this has to do with the network drivers, but I know nothing about this. Here is some information about my computer:

```
***lsb_release -a***

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal


***uname -a***
Linux Filipe-PC 5.4.0-91-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 16:31:28 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


***rfkill list***
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

*** ífconfig***
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:f6:63:15:4c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.104  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::8250:952a:2c8d:4cb3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b0:6e:bf:18:a1:43  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 386316  bytes 565360952 (565.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 141792  bytes 11451889 (11.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 127  base 0x5000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 186  bytes 12031 (12.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 186  bytes 12031 (12.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:9f:e8:51  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

***sudo lshw -C network***
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: b0:6e:bf:18:a1:43
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.00-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.0.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:127 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:ef404000-ef404fff memory:ef400000-ef403fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 31
       serial: 40:9f:38:41:7d:25
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.4.0-91-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:131 memory:ef200000-ef3fffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:9f:e8:51
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

If you need more information, please let me know. This situation has been present for 2 years and I decided to sit down and fix it.

**Edit**

Here is the output requested:

```
***sudo cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state***

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
```

Comment: Please run `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1sysctl -w && net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1`

Comment: @someone, the problem persists

Comment: Can you [edit] the post and add the output of `cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state`

Comment: @someone edited!

Comment: For people who also run docker, see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1060723

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling/decreasing the Wi-Fi power saver:

```
 sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

---

If disabling the power-saver didn't work then try:

```
sudo rm -rf /lib/firmware/ath10k && sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

Comment: This conversation was [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132515/discussion-between-someone-and-filipe-miguel)

Comment: still not working with my laptop. do I need to re-install OS?

Comment: @huykon225 Did the issue happened all of a sudden, or was it from initally installing the OS...?

Comment: @Error404 yes this issue is happening usually on my chrome browser. it's not issue with firefox.

Comment: @huykon225 Ah! Did this issue happen after some certain "activity", or was it out of the box from chrome browser? In either the situations, the problem should be solved by reinstalling the OS, because it does not appear to be a driver issue, but either way, I'd recommend to wait and try to fix the issue on your current installation to avoid loss of data/time...

Comment: @Error404 yeah I think the best solution is reinstall Ubuntu =))))