# Dell Latitude 3490: Problem with ath10k QCA6174 + Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, dell

happy new year!

I own a Dell Latitude 3490 and since I've changed the OS from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 20.04 i've found some problems with WiFi connection. Connection drops, connections failing, slow internet speed (my link is up to 300Mb/s but on that Latitude only reach ~40Mb/s). I've followed some guides here on Askubuntu and over the internet but nothing changed this scenarios. Can someone bring me a light up, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extremely slow internet. Wifi keeps dropping down ath10k](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382457/err-network-changed-keeps-appearing-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Have you tried my troubleshooting tips here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Pls elaborate on the solutions you have tried and their results.

Comment: Pls elaborate on the solutions you have tried and their results.

Comment: Hello everybody! I solved my problem upgrading Ubuntu to 21.04!