# Websites aren't loading in chrome (ERR_TIMED_OUT) but do in firefox

Tags: networking, firefox, google-chrome, https

I have got a problem since Ubuntu 16.04 (still here in Ubuntu 18.04):

Some websites like https://github.com/ or https://bugs.launchpad.net/ aren't available in Chrome. I get an `ERR_TIMED_OUT` after some loading time. If I try loading the same website in firefox it takes some seconds but they are loaded correctly.
If I try reloading the url several times in Chrome, at some point the website loads correctly. After a first full load I can browse through the website without any problems.

I tested it with LAN and WLAN, also in other networks and with a fresh chrome installation without add-ons. Problem still exists. If I am booting Windows (dual boot) the websites directly loads successful so the problem must be in the Ubuntu system.

Comment: Is this happening for `HTTPS` sites in general?

Comment: Good question. Could be. Since lately "all" pages uses `HTTPS` I haven't found a non-SSL page with this problem yet.

Comment: I don't think that it is a chrome related issue because the sites also takes a long time loading in firefox.

Comment: Does flushing the DNS Cache help? Try it using `sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean restart`

Comment: No, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using docker on your system, then as [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/909631/938234) said remove useless docker networks and everything will be fine. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck on browser and it was probably because I was running some docker containers, it caused this issue. I removed all the containers, images, docker network as well. Unfortunately, none of them worked for me. However, thanks to A J it was made clear for us. Go to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/440649) and follow the instructions them step by step.

Try to stop all your running docker containers and prune your docker network. `docker network prune` may help you, but in my case it did not work as well. I deleted Chrome browser completely, but it also did not work as well. Some forms suggested to if you have same problem try to disable IPv6 in Network.

At first, I thought how that could be related, apparently, people in Chrome's forum says you need to that in order not to get stuck in browser, just giving you quick commands:

In order to disable IPv6, open with:

```
nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

insert at the end what is given below:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

If IPv6 is still not disabled, then the problem is that sysctl.conf is still not activated.

To solve this, open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type the command:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

You will see this in the terminal:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Run the following command:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

that will output:

```
1
```

which IPv6 has been successfully disabled.

Comment: No, none of them. given link is solution to the occurred problem but it is not duplicate questions,  they are just related to this issue, in order to fix Chrome ERR_TIMED_OUT, you need to disable ipv6, and the answer is given in the link how to disable it. Whoever had this issue with Chrome says disable ipv6.

Comment: Is that makes it clear? I completely explained the problem gave the solution as well.

Comment: Thanks! Seriously this worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04. I  just disabled ipv6 and everything started working fine.